# Does the function 'load_file()' in MySQL must use path from the server?

Tags: mysql

This is the current only path I can use `load_file()` function in MySQL:

```
 C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads
```

Can I not attach any other file from any other path?

Because I am able to attach `BLOB` file attachment only from the path mentioned above. But attaching a path from a `\Desktop` or else where.. shows values as `null`.

Can this be altered? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

> Reads the file and returns the file contents as a string. To use this function, the file must be located on the server host, you must specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the FILE privilege. The file must be readable by all and its size less than max_allowed_packet bytes. **If the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.**

Comment: I see it says **"Must"**, take that as a no then?